# How to select (highlight) an Item in an already existing listbox 

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, winforms

I have an already existing `listbox` and need to show up the value that I have retrieved from the DB on it.

Here need to check for values before insert, if its already exists, looking for way to highlight the existing item.

Here is the code I am using

```
try { 
     myConnection.Open(); 
     SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientDataFields where  PatientID='" + x + "'", myConnection); 
     SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand2.ExecuteReader(); 

     while (rdr.Read()) 
     { 
         Form2 form2 = new Form2(); 
         form2.Show();
         form2.Race.SelectedItem = rdr["Race"].ToString();
     } 
    }
```

Comment: Is this winforms, wpf, or asp.net? We can't even begin to answer until we know at least that.

Comment: Can we see what you have done so far please !!! Also seems like your question title have more information than question description... please take some time to look at **http://stackoverflow.com/faq**

Comment: In winforms. I have used the following code.
            try
            {

                myConnection.Open();

                SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientDataFields where PatientID='" + x + "'", myConnection);
                SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    
                    Form2 form2 = new Form2();
                    form2.Show();form2.Race.SelectedItem = rdr["Race"].ToString();}

Comment: The code above doesn't show how you have filled the ListBox. (Have you already filled it with the possible items right?) I suppose you have filled a listbox named `Race` with string items. You need to Highlight the one matching the value retrieved from db. Am I right or not?

Comment: Yes, you are right Steve

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this, and make sure value return from db must exists in listbox control items

If database value is in the Text field of listBox (DataTextField)

```
listbox.SelectedText = valueFromDB;
```

Or If database value is in the value field of listBox (DataValueField)

```
listbox.SelectedValue = valueFromDB;
```

Comment: I am unable to see the item being highlighted in the list box with the the value retrieved from DB using the above comments.

Comment: what do you mean by highlighted, do you mean selected ?

Comment: This is the way it works. I submitted some values from a Form(say Form1) into the DB. So the Form1 consists of textboxes, listboxes etc.. Now from another form(say form2) I'm calling form1 to show the values I have submitted before to the DB. So the Db should return already submitted values.

Comment: Thats good, value should exists in the listbox to get selected

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have multiple selection, make sure you set SelectionMode to MultiSimple. Rest of your code looks fine to me.

```
try 
{ 
    myConnection.Open(); 
    SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM PatientDataFields where  PatientID='" + x + "'", myConnection); 
    SqlDataReader rdr = myCommand2.ExecuteReader(); 

    Form2 form2 = new Form2(); 
    form2.Show();
    form2.Race.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiSimple;
    while (rdr.Read()) 
    {
        string item = rdr["Race"].ToString();

        if (form2.Race.FindString(item) != -1)
            form2.Race.SelectedItem = item;
        else
            form2.Race.Items.Add(item);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a tonne..!!The issue was that I hadn't trimmed off the spaces from the values that I had retrieved from the DB